# How can I adjust by how much the sound volume changes every time I press the volume change keys?

Tags: linux, audio, ubuntu-9.10

For example if the volume is 48 and I press the volume up key the new value will be 56. What would I have to do to make it go to 52?

I use both keyboard and remote control keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to change the volume step interval, this is fairly easy.

- Open up the terminal and run the command `gconf-editor`, it will bring up this window:

  [image]
- In the left pane, expand **apps** and click on **gnome_settings_daemon**:

  [image]
- double click the **volume_step** key in the right pane, enter the new **step value** (this is the value you want the volume to change by when you press **volume up** or **volume down** on your keyboard), and press OK:

  [image]
- test your new configuration and exit gconf-editor if all is working!

Comment: You're very welcome :)

Comment: is there a way to do this over the terminal?

Comment: this setting appears to have disappeared now :(

Answer (score 1):

Here is a hard core way (read old school way) to do it.  Use `xev` to tell you what the codes for the keys you want to use are.  Then use something like (in $HOME/.xsession)

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode 171 = XF86AudioNext'
xmodmap -e 'keycode 173 = XF86AudioPrev'
```

to get the keys mapped to actions.  Then you can modify your $HOME/.fvwm2rc to have

```
Key XF86AudioPrev               A       C       Exec exec nyxmms2 prev
Key XF86AudioNext               A       C       Exec exec nyxmms2 next
```

Restart fvwm2 and you are done.

Comment: old school ways are powerful! :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using a laptop or one of those enhanced keyboards..? If so, careful because

- ubuntu 9.10 has pulse audio; aumix is alsa-related and might take you down the wrong path
- what you need is probably something like xmodmap (if it can capture your key), or if you're on a laptop there should be a kernel module/applet able to capture the specific key press. On some (my old ASUS) I had to go through ACPI to access the volume key.