# Changing the size of the audio volume increment of the "volume up" / "volume down" keys

Tags: windows, audio, keyboard

Same as this question but for Windows: [How can I adjust by how much the sound volume changes every time I press the volume change keys?](https://superuser.com/questions/91032/how-can-i-adjust-by-how-much-the-sound-volume-changes-every-time-i-press-the-vol)

I'm on a Windows 7 laptop. It has "volume up" and "volume down" keys on the keyboard. Pressing them changes the volume by a tiny amount. Is there a setting or registry key or something to change that amount, or will I have to install third-party software to do it?

Comment: I've been looking for this sort of thing off and on for years with no luck. The best I've found is to use a third-party volume control app.

Comment: I've now installed 3RVX, which lets me adjust this and also provides a reasonable on-screen volume display. http://matthew.malensek.net/software/

Comment: Can somebody tell how to modify the hard coded value 51 or hook `IAudioEndpointVolume::VolumeStepUp()`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes a third-party app seems to be the best solution.

Microsoft's [response](https://web.archive.org/web/20101101132353/http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowspro-audiodevelopment/thread/fa71e319-f1f2-4382-ad69-6a49e534511a) to the problem is this:

> The keypresses are sent to the OS as APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_UP and
> APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_DOWN HID messages.  These are then translated to
> calls to IAudioEndpointVolume::VolumeStepUp() or
> IAudioEndpointVolume::VolumeStepDown(); this is hardcoded to 51 steps.
>
> Possible mitigations are to toy with the keyboard refresh rate in the
> Control Panel or to write an app that listens for the
> APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_UP HID messages and does its own thing.

Some laptop manufacturers provide a third-party application that captures special keypresses and provides OSD etc, and this might be customizable.

Otherwise I'd also recommend [3RVX](https://3rvx.com/) as per your comments.

Comment: On my Windows 8.1 box, I am able to increment/decrement the volume by left-clicking the volume icon in the tool tray and then pressing the up/down arrows.

Comment: 3RVX doesn't seem to allow adjusting increment...

Answer (score 5):

In contrary to the OP my aim was to reduce the increment from 2% to 1% for my in-ear-phones. My workaround without having to install 3rd party software was to reduce the volume of the source (e.g. media player) to 50%. Since final volume = source volume * taskbar volume the 2%-steps are now effectively 1%-steps (I never need more than 20% of the max volume)

Answer (score 5):

The must satisfying way I found is to use an [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) script. As you might know, AutoHotKey can intercept keyboard event and do a lot of things. The script I use is the following:

```
~Volume_Up::SoundSet, +8
~Volume_Down::SoundSet, -8
```

In my case, the default volume increment is 2. I want to make it 10, so here I add/substract 8 more units (the ~ symbol at the beginning means "do not block default action", so the default volume action, including showing the system OSD, still work as normal), and it works perfectly.

Comment: I approve the AutoHotkey recommendation: a lot of customization ability without the need of complex scripting.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the open source [3RVX program](//3rvx.com):

1. Settings
2. Hotkeys
3. +
4. Keys
5. Action: Increase Volume
6. Amount: 10 Percent

Note that 3RVX also has [skins beyond](//github.com/malensek/3RVX/tree/master/Skins) what comes with the release. For
example, I am using the “Windows Default” skin. What is also useful is that you
can customize these skins by modifying the skin.xml file. I [changed mine](//github.com/svnpenn/dotfiles/blob/2e32c10/volume/skin.xml)
to increase the font size.

Answer (score 4):

I also had [user829755's](https://superuser.com/questions/359138/changing-the-size-of-the-audio-volume-increment-of-the-volume-up-volume-dow/1180901#1180901) problem (needing smaller increments instead of larger). Since [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1332215/increase-and-decrease-volume-by-1-instead-of-2?noredirect=1&lq=1) was closed as a duplicate of this one, but I didn't get the full answer I needed there, I thought I'd extend the AutoHotkey answer to cover the case of odd volume increments:

```
; Fix Windows Volume:
$Volume_Up::
    SoundGet, volume 
    Send {Volume_Up}
    SoundSet, volume + 1
Return

$Volume_Down::
    SoundGet, volume 
    Send {Volume_Down}
    SoundSet, volume - 1
Return
```

Like [Mu-Tsun Tsai's](https://superuser.com/questions/359138/changing-the-size-of-the-audio-volume-increment-of-the-volume-up-volume-dow/1451204#1451204) answer, this is an [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) script. One key difference is that it sends the volume command to Endpoint *first* (which sets the volume to the next highest/lowest even value and brings up the graphical display), then ignores the default action and overwrites the volume with the value I want.

Comment: This is great, but the repeated `Send {Volume_Up}` glitches the OSD a bit (it'll show volume changing +2 and then -1). You can instead use this snippet to display the OSD after `SoundSet`:

Comment: ```
    try if ((shellProvider := ComObjCreate("{C2F03A33-21F5-47FA-B4BB-156362A2F239}", "{00000000-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"))) {
        try if ((flyoutDisp := ComObjQuery(shellProvider, "{41f9d2fb-7834-4ab6-8b1b-73e74064b465}", "{41f9d2fb-7834-4ab6-8b1b-73e74064b465}"))) {
                DllCall(NumGet(NumGet(flyoutDisp+0)+3*A_PtrSize), "Ptr", flyoutDisp, "Int", 0, "UInt", 0)
            ,ObjRelease(flyoutDisp)
        }
        ObjRelease(shellProvider)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

My preference to solve this is [Volume2](https://github.com/irzyxa/Volume2)! Info on the app can be found on [AlternativeTo](https://alternativeto.net/software/volume2/about/). Volume2 (volume squared) has a lot of customizability, for example allows you to change the volume with the scroll wheel and change the size of the audio volume increment, down to 1 in my case. You can also support them on the [Microsoft Store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/volume-advanced-windows-volume-control/9p53twr6lctx?rtc=1&activetab=pivot:overviewtab).

I use Windows 11 and the AHK scripts gave me issues where it would suddenly mute at different intervals because it would recognize both changes -- system and AHK -- and when I changed the volume fast it would mute every time. The explanation is confusing but that's the jist.

@Zombo mentioned 3RVX, I tried it out and it works but has some bugs, and isn't maintained since 2017, still works though.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked for me was 'Volume Step Adjuster'.
I also tried 3RVX, EarTrumpet, and Volume2, but none did the job.