# Limit volume range Windows 10

Tags: windows, audio

I'm having following problem:

When using speaker, my volume is set to 50%, which we will take as baseline.
When using headphones using audio jack, volume level corresponding to baseline is 4%. Which consequently means, that anything above 10% is too loud.

I would like to limit range of headphone output, so that:

1. it would not go over current 10%
2. it would be possible to adjust volume level more precisely (current 10% would be "new" 100% for headphones: as such going from current 4% to 5% would be going from 40% to 50%)

What are my options?

Answer (score 5):

I found those programs:

---

[3RVX](https://3RVX.com)  (look at [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/359138/changing-the-size-of-the-audio-volume-increment-of-the-volume-up-volume-dow)).

This one is the best of those four, but needs some configuration first to work as desired. It locks windows volume toolbar level (it can't go higher than limit). And it is open source.

3RVX also allows to adjust volume level more precisely (for example I have 13 steps instead of 9 in 0-8% range). Number of steps depend on chosen skin. It can be edited in skin's xml.

---

[Quiet on the Set](https://github.com/troylar/quiet-on-the-set)

It is compatible with 3RVX, you can use both at the same time.

It also locks windows volume toolbar level (it can't go higher than limit). And it is also open source.

---

[Sound Lock](https://www.3appes.com/sound-lock/)

This one does not work really good if you want to have lock at certain system volume, it will change lock depending on music loudness. I don't recommend it.

---

[VolumeLock](http://www.actualsolution.com/volume-lock/)

Trial version, I didn't test it

---

Comment: `Quiet on the Set` works good. `Sound Lock` doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Had to use 2 tools to make sound level of headphones quieter:

Install Equalizer APO on playback device.
https://sourceforge.net/projects/equalizerapo/

Using Peace Equalizer, set "Pre amplifying" to -30dB
https://sourceforge.net/projects/peace-equalizer-apo-extension/

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the *internal* speakers, and headphones are on a separate audio jack, see if your version of Windows 10 and hardware driver allow the volume to be set separately. For example, open the *Sound* control panel application (CPL), right-click on each *Playback* device, select *Properties*, and set gain (and balance) on the *Levels* tab.

[image: Setting *Headphone* level]

If you are using *external* speakers, using the audio out jack (as opposed to the internal speakers), then there is no way that the PC can tell whether your speakers or your phones are connected. Use *hardware* to resolve the issue: either buy an [external inline volume control](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008DJTB32) (~US$8.00), or, if you have the technical skill, splice two resistors into the headphone cable (~US$0.50) (you might need somewhere between 47 and 1,000 ohms for desired level, experiment).

Comment: Ron White should have said.... 
"You can buy a simple external inline volume control or you can experiment with a resistor somewhere between 47 and 1,000 ohms; it is the same price"

Comment: Not sure I understand that... $8 = $.50? For very large values of "same"?

Comment: On Amazon, a resistor assortment is a bit more the $0.50 shipped.  I get it, Ebay from china is under $2.00, but amazon-for-amazon, technically the resistors are more expensive at first glance.  overall I was thinking they were "generally" the same price. :).  Alright, joke is killed now.

Comment: You're correct, though, that if you need to buy the parts, then it may be cheaper to just get the ready-made product. The alternative is only useful to an electronics hacker. Sorry I didn't get your reference.

Comment: http://grabbingthestarfish.blogspot.com/2012/02/you-can-take-donkey-or-you-can-take.html  And don't worry, I am usually the one taking things "too liteally" in my house.  Nice to not be the only one!

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using all 8 supported channels (L,R,C,Sub,RL,RR,SL,SR), you can abuse one of them to set a limit.

1. set global volume to the maximum that you want
2. navigate to "balance" settings:

   1. open system settings, system, then sound
   2. go to device properties
   3. additional device properties (on the right)
   4. "levels" tab
   5. balance button
3. pull any one of the unused channels all the way to 100 and leave the others where they are.

Observe that the global system volume now seems to be at 100%, while the channels that are actually in use are still at their previous volume.  When changing the volume via the task bar volume control, observe how that proportionally changes the channel volumes in "balance".  In other words, you can now use the full 0-100 range and do fine-grained volume adjustments, while in actuality it will only use the limited range that you set.

No external programs nor additional hardware needed, all you need to do is think like a Microsoft software engineer! ;)  (Only took me about 4 hours to find this workaround/hack...)

---

[image: same steps described above repeated as image]

Comment: But if you lower your volume to 0 at any point, you reset your balance and your limit is gone.

Answer (score 1):

**Windows built-in tools will let you do this.**

The instructions below use "Volume Mixer", but the newer "sound mixer options" probably works in a similar way.

Volume mixer will let you set a scaling factor between the Device volume (a.k.a. master volume) and each application. Initially you get a 1:1 scaling of Device/master volume to each app, but you can use sliders to adjust all of the app volumes downward which effectively caps the max volume of each app. The volume range will still go from 0-100 but you can make 100 as quiet as you'd like.

1. Open Volume mixer by right-clicking the speaker icon in the system tray:

   [image: speaker icon in systray]
2. Look at the list of apps in Volume mixer. Apps only show up in Volume mixer if they've recently played audio, so if any of your favorites are missing from this list you'll need to open them and get them to play some audio (and then pause it), and then (re)open Volume mixer.
3. Adjust the leftmost slider (Device) to 100, and move all the other sliders to 1 so you don't blow out your speakers while you're following the rest of the steps.
4. Start with first app in the list. If that app has its own volume control, make sure it's maxed out. For the browser you can use YouTube and move its slider. Now tell your app to play audio. Back Volume mixer, move the Volume mixer slider for that app upward until it's as loud as you'd ever want it to be. It is now capped to that volume. Pause the audio from that app (you could also just close the app).
5. Repeat step #4 for each of the remaining apps in the list.

   Some system sounds play even if you've turned off all the system sounds (which is how I like it). To test the ones that ignore, I pressed shift 5 times. This plays a ding noise even with the sounds turned off, probably because shift 5 times triggers an accessibility feature and those have special rules. Just click the 'cancel' button when the 'Sticky Keys' (eew) menu comes up. Also it's faster than opening up the system sounds menu and pressing the play button if you only have to do it once or twice.
6. You're all set. Now a device volume of 100 will correspond to the app volumes (maximums) that you've just set, effectively capping them to those values. You can close Volume mixer.

If you Don't normally listen at the maximum volume you've set, you can use your the normal Device/master volume slider (in system tray, or from a special button on your keyboard, or any number of other places) to lower it now.

If you later realize that you missed an app, you can go through steps 1-3 again and then do step 4 just for that app.

I found this solution when I was trying to fix my sound bar volume. Volume level 14, was the loudest I ever wanted it, and that was for playing music so I could hear it in the next room. My volume +/- buttons on the my keyboard incremented and decremented the volume by 2, and volume 2 was inaudible so I effectively only had four volume levels to choose from. After making these adjustments, my comfortable volume level is 50 and I have a wide range to adjust it up and down from there.

This solution accommodates multiple output devices too, and it saves all of the slider values for each device separately. You may have noticed that Volume mixer has a dropdown menu above the leftmost slider where you can choose a different device. IGNORE IT. If you change the device in Volume mixer, you will only see one slider. Instead, CLOSE Volume mixer and then left-click the speaker system tray icon, choose the other device from the dropdown menu, then open Volume mixer again. If you're clicking on the tray icon and nothing is happening, Volume mixer is probably still open.

Here's what my Volume mixer levels look like now:
[image: Volume mixer app]

Answer (score 0):

In case you got some "audio enhancement" software with your motherboard or sound card, which has an **equalizer**:

1. Move all sliders to the **same level** around **-10db**
2. **Tune it** from there like -10db would be the zero level, until it sounds good
3. **Save** it as a **profile** and make it **default**

Depending on the software you may have to do it separately for each output device you're using.

Worked well for me with ASUS ROG Sonic Studio 3. Should work with other similar audio enhancement tools or equalizers, like Equalizer APO or the Realtek Audio Console.