# Volume hot keys: How can I configure the number of volume-steps on Debian?

Tags: audio, debian, hotkeys, volume-mixer

I have a good DAC and a strong amplifier. I use Debian and sometimes I just can't get the volume gain to be as I wish to using the hot keys. I've noticed that each time I hit them, the volume increases or decreases 6%.

> How can I change this percentage to say 1% ?

[this solution](https://superuser.com/a/92526/202217) is not possible on Debian.

Comment: Related to the non-working solution, [it appears to now be hardcoded](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-settings-daemon/tree/plugins/media-keys/gsd-media-keys-manager.c#n107) for whatever reason in two commits in 2010.  According to [this wonderful bug report](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=650371) (and some of the related threads/comments), it seems that this is unlikely to change due to developer arrogance. [This thread](http://askubuntu.com/questions/10525/how-can-i-make-the-volume-change-in-smaller-increments) should offer a suitable solution.

Comment: Thanx a lot for the info! To read the comments is really amusing ^_^ (except for the fact that there is no solution yet!) I wonder id this is solvable in a non-Gnome-Debian? Do you know if something like that exists?

Comment: It entirely depends on the distro. No reason a different distro can't implement it in a different way. The sure-fire way to know is to check source code, or rely on third party tools to provide the desired functionality. I am not familiar with non-Gnome Debian, what exactly are you using instead of Gnome?

Comment: I am using Gnome and it is my 1st time on Debian - only personal use... I recall seeing KDE-Debian somewhere...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not yet found a way to configure exactly what I want, but by now I do have a workaround:

I installed the `alsa-tools` package: "A collection of console-based utilities for specific sound hardware". When I open it thorough terminal and press F3 I can control the volume gain with the vertical cursor keys and with each strike I change 1% of the gain!   :)

So, my hot-key-combination is Alt+Tab (to the terminal window with AlsaMixer) + Up (or Down) for a 1% volume change.