# Change volume steps in Kubuntu from 5% to 1%

Tags: linux, ubuntu, audio, kde, kubuntu

Every time you hit the Volume Up or Volume Down key on Linux Kubuntu, the volume changes by 5%.

However, I would like to change that so the volume only gets adjusted by 1%. I tried [this solution](https://superuser.com/questions/91032/how-can-i-adjust-by-how-much-the-sound-volume-changes-every-time-i-press-the-vol/92526#92526), which doesn't work on Kubuntu (or I just didn't realize how), I also googled everywhere but did not find a working solution, and also ChatGPT had no working ideas.

So, can anyone of you help me?

Comment: Indeed. The solution you tried is applicable to Gnome DE only. Kubuntu runs with KDE. Try searching for KDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System Settings > Audio > Configure Volume Controls > Volume Change Step.

If you are using an old Plasma version (< 5.27): Right-click on the audio applet in the panel > Configure.

Comment: Thank you very much, at least there was the option. I hope it works now, but only after the reboot ig.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did to change the volume step for Kubuntu 22.04:

1. Right-click on the speaker icon on the taskbar
2. Click "Configure Audio Volume..."
3. Change the "Volume step:" field to the desired percentage (i.e. 1%)